# SQLAlchemy migrations generating foreign keys with different names. How to drop these?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

In my SQLAlchemy data model I had a reference from `project->customer`. I am doing migrations and initially this FK was created via

```
sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['customer_id'], ['customers.id'], )
```

(this was during the same migration that created the `project` table so the auto generated `down` is to simply `drop_table`).

Now I am removing this reference and hence dropping that constraint. The auto-generated migration for it is

```
op.drop_constraint('FK__projects__custom__412EB0B6', 'projects', type_='foreignkey')
```

The problem is that the constraint *isn't always named that*. In one database I checked its named `FK__projects__custom__2E1BDC42`, in another yet another thing...How do I drop the constraint properly and whats causing the difference in names?

**Edit:**
Apparently [I had the option to name the constraint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint) ... which the docs don't of course mention being a good and necessary idea. So...I know how to prevent this in the future, but not how to fix the current issue.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Mssql?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Sql Server

Comment: Perhaps you could query [`sys.foreign_keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-keys-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) during migration in order to find out the actual name of the constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding this to my migration

```
op.execute("""
    DECLARE @fk_project_customer varchar(50);
    SELECT @fk_project_customer = (SELECT name FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE name LIKE 'FK__projects__custom__%');
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE projects DROP CONSTRAINT "' + @fk_project_customer + '"');
""")
```

So it basically finds the constraint name that follows this pattern from `sys.foreign_keys` as @Ilja recommended, then `EXEC` a dynamic sql query from it